# Getting two errors in C program

Tags: c, arrays, switch-statement

I'm going to post my code below, and then specify my issues below as well.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

//initializing the array
int arrayElements(array)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= strlen(array); i++)
    {
        printf("Enter array element:\n");
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    }
    printf("Elements: ");
    for (int i = 0; i <= strlen(array); i++)
    {
        printf("%d, ", array[i]);
    }
}

//sorting the array
int arraySort(int array)
{
    char sortType;
    printf("Sort in Ascending or Descending order? [A\D]\n");
    scanf("%c", &sortType);
    while ((sortType != "A") || (sortType != "D"))
    {
        printf("Invalid selection.\n");
        printf("Sort in Ascending or Descending order? [A\D]\n");
        scanf("%c", &sortType);
    }
    if (sortType == "A")
    {
        ascending(array);
    }
    else
    {
        descending(array);
    }
}

//searching the array
int arrayFind(int * array)
{
    int searchElement;
    int *d;
    int i;
    int **string;
    printf("What element do you wish to search for?");
    scanf("%d", &searchElement);
    d = strint (array, searchElement);

    if (d != NULL)
    {
        for (i = 0; i <= strlen(array); i++)
        {
            if (string[i] == searchElement)
            {
                printf("Element found at array[%d]\n", i);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Element '%d' not found\n", searchElement);
    }
}

//printing the array
int arrayPrint(array)
{
    printf("%d", array);
}

//printing array in reverse order
int arrayRevPrint(array)
{
    int **size;
    for (size = strlen(array); size >= 0 ; size--)
    {
        printf("%d",array[size]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int userSelection;
    int size;
    int elements;
    int searchElement;
    while (userSelection != 7)
    {
        printf("Please enter your selection\n>");
        printf("1 - Enter the size of the array:\n");
        printf("2 - Enter the array elements:\n");
        printf("3 - Sort the array\n");
        printf("4 - Find a number within the array\n");
        printf("5 - Print the array\n");
        printf("6 - Reverse print the array\n");
        printf("7 - Quit\n");
        scanf("%d", &userSelection);

        switch (userSelection)
        {
        case 1 :
        size=0;

        while ((size > 20) || (size < 1))
        {
            printf("What is the size of your array? (1 - 20)\n");
            scanf("%d", &size);
            if ((size > 20) || (size < 1))
            {
                printf("Invalid selection.\n");
            }
        int *array[size];
        printf("\nSize of array: array[%d]\nReturning...", size);
        break;
        }

        case 2 :
            if (size == 0)
            {
                printf("You should first set the size of the array.\n");
            }
            else
            {
                arrayElements(array);
            }
        case 3 :
            if (elements == NULL)
            {
                printf("You should first intitialize the array.\n");
            }
            else
            {
                arraySort(array);
            }
        case 4 :
            if (elements == NULL)
            {
                printf("You should first intitialize the array.\n");
            }
            else
            {
                int arrayFind(array);
            }
        case 5 :
            if (elements == NULL)
            {
                printf("You should first intitialize the array.\n");
            }
            else
            {
                arrayPrint(array);
            }
        case 6 :
            if (elements == NULL)
            {
                printf("You should first intitialize the array.\n");
            }
            else
            {
                arrayRevPrint(array);
            }
        case 7 :
            printf("Exiting...");
                return 0;
        default :
            printf("That's not a valid choice\n");
        }
    }

}
```

Now, there are two main issues I'm running into. I'll post just one of each, because I'm getting a bunch of them for different lines.

The first is,

```
error at line 137: switch jumps into scope of identifier with variably modified type.
```

The second is

```
error at line 10: subscripted value is neither an array nor pointer nor vector
```

Also, I'm trying to understand why I have to redeclare `int size;` in some of the functions, if I've already declared it in the main function.

Any advice would be much appreciated. Thank you
PS, this is for an intro to C assignment, I know it's crappy. But if I can get it to work, I can ignore the warnings.

Comment: I can't compile and use your code... it has a lot of errors

Comment: First line is wrong - missing a type; 'int arrayElements(array)'.  Second line is wrong: 'for (int i = 0; i <= strlen(array); i++)' is Obi-Wan wrong. It indexes the array off the end.  Third line looks OK, 4th close, OK mod the aray indexing from line 2.

Comment: in line 10 change `scanf("%d", &array[i]);` with `scanf("%d", array[i]);` and add `break` in every case of `switch-statement`. Without break it'll fall through and execute every code of every case

Comment: Line 6 has the same Obi-Wan issue as line 2.

Comment: Lines 2 and 6 call strlen() repeatedly and unnecessarily, but that's only an inefficiency.

Comment: Aside: `scanf("%c", &sortType);` could be `scanf(" %c", &sortType);` to clean off leading whitespace.

Comment: Aside `while ((sortType != "A") || (sortType != "D"))` should be `while ((sortType != 'A') && (sortType != 'D'))` ~ doubly buggy!

Comment: This code has a lot of bug.. Please edit the code

Comment: In main(): 'while (userSelection != 7)' var used uninitialized.

Comment: What @surjit says ^^^^^^^^^^  too many syntax etc. errors.

Comment: Yet more: the `case` statements lack the `break;` so each falls thru to the next.

Comment: The compount while() statements are illogical.  Don't write compound boolean expressions directly - you will get them wrong, as you have done here.  Use temp booleans for easier understanding and debugging.

Comment: You should go back to the basics, and learn the syntax before you try something like this. Also, when you're writing code, don't write 175 lines without even compiling let alone testing the code, or this kind of a mess happens. Try going through [this tutorial](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial.html)

Comment: go reread your C text book, start from the basics..

Comment: "But if I can get it to work, I can ignore the warnings."-- Until you really know what you are doing, don't ignore _any_ warnings. Fix them all. Warnings usually point to an actual problem that will bite you sooner or later. Sometimes fixing a warning fixes an error that occurs later in the code that may _seem_ unrelated. Fix them; make it a habit. And compile with plenty of warnings enabled. I _always_ use at least `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic`, and if you add `-Werror` the compiler won't _allow_ code with warnings to compile. This is a good way to enforce the fixing of warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has way to many errors to be compiled. There seem to be a lot of fundamental mistakes in your code with respect to using pointers. I will try to point out a few of them in your code and you could start with rectifying them first. I assume you are looking to initialize an array with 'size' elements.

```
int *array[size];
```

In switch: case 1 the above declaration means you are initializing an array of 'size' number of integer pointers. You might want to initialize it as`int *array = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * size);`

Next for all the funtions you need the parameter passed to the function to be an integer pointer. I will rectify your arrayelement() function and you can make the same changes to the other functions as well. Also in the for loop you are calculating the length of the array wrong. This is the corrected version of the arrayElement() function:

```
    int arrayElements(int *array)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ((strlen(array))/sizeof(int)); i++)
        {
            printf("Enter array element:\n");
            scanf("%d", &array[i]);
        }
        printf("Elements: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < ((strlen(array))/sizeof(int)); i++)
        {
            printf("%d, ", array[i]);
        }
    }
```

Similarly change the parameter passed to all of the functions to `funcName(int *array)`. And also calculate the size of the array as: `((strlen(array))/sizeof(int))`.

And 'size' is a local variable of your main() function. If you do not want to initialize it in all of the functions you can just pass it as a parameter to all the functions instead or you can make 'size' a global variable. These are some of the very evident mistakes in your code.

Comment: you cant do `int *array[size];` since the variable `size` is not known when it's compiled (the user defines it during runtime), you need to use `malloc`

Comment: @jacoblaw Okay yes my bad I did not consider that. I wanted to make the point that `int *array[size]` will be an array of integer pointers instead of an array of integers. I will correct that in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There were a lot of errors both logical and syntatical. I removed all the syntatical errors and almost all the logical ones too. I have commented the faults that were in your code and how I edited that. Please have a look at the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
// Its a good practice to mention your definitions of functions on the top.
void arrayElements(int arr[], int size);
void arraySort(int arr[], int size);
void arrayPrint(int arr[], int size);
void arrayRevPrint(int arr[], int size); 
void arrayFind(int arr[], int size);

//initializing the array
//Function not returning anything use void instead of int
void arrayElements(int arr[], int size) // Modified signature
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i <= size; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter array element:\n");
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }
    //Since you just want to print the array you can directly call arrayPrint() function.
    // printf("Elements: ");
    // for (i = 0; i <= size; i++)
    // {
    //     printf("%d, ", arr[i]);
    // }
    arrayPrint(arr,size);
}

//sorting the array
//Function not returning anything use void instead of int
void arraySort(int arr[], int size) // Modified signature
{
    char sortType;
    printf("Sort in Ascending or Descending order? [A\\D]\n"); // to use an escape charachter
                                                               // use \ before them. 
                            //To know more about escape characters please surf the internet.
    scanf("%c", &sortType);
    // Character literal are always bound between single quotes.
    while ((sortType != 'A') || (sortType != 'D'))
    {
        printf("Invalid selection.\n");
        printf("Sort in Ascending or Descending order? [A\\D]\n");
        scanf("%c", &sortType);
    }
    // Where are the functions ascending and descending declared??
    // Define the functions.
    if (sortType == 'A')
    {
        //ascending(arr);  
    }
    else
    {
        //descending(arr);
    }
}

//searching the array
//Function not returning anything use void instead of int
void arrayFind(int arr[], int size)// Modified signature 
{
    int searchElement;
    //int *d; No need of this
    bool found = false; // A flag which we will turn true if element found.
    int i;
    //int **string; No need of this
    printf("What element do you wish to search for?");
    scanf("%d", &searchElement);
    //d = strint (array, searchElement); No need of this

    //if (d != NULL) 
    //{
        for (i = 0; i <= size; i++)
        {
            if (arr[i] == searchElement)
            {
                printf("Element found at array[%d]\n", i);
                found = true;
                break; // Element has been found so for coming out of the loop
            }
        }
        if (found == false)
        {
            printf("Element %d not found \n", searchElement);
        }
    // No need of the extra code below
    //}
    // else
    // {
    //     printf("Element '%d' not found\n", searchElement);
    // }
}

//printing the array
//Function not returning anything use void instead of int
void arrayPrint(int arr[], int size) // Modified signature 
{
    // You can not print array like this in c.
    //printf("%d", array);

    // To print an array in c you have to loop through it.
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<size; i++){
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }
}

//printing array in reverse order
//Function not returning anything use void instead of int
void arrayRevPrint(int arr[], int size) // Modified signature
{
    int i;
    for (i=size-1; i >= 0 ; i--)
    {
        printf("%d ",arr[i]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int userSelection;
    int size;
    bool elements = false; // I guess you wanted it to use as a flag for whether there
                  // there are elements in the array or not.
                  // In order to do that better use a boolean and set its default value
                  // to false.
    int searchElement;
    int *arr;  // Your Dynamic array
    while (userSelection != 7)
    {
        printf("Please enter your selection\n>");
        printf("1 - Enter the size of the array:\n");
        printf("2 - Enter the array elements:\n");
        printf("3 - Sort the array\n");
        printf("4 - Find a number within the array\n");
        printf("5 - Print the array\n");
        printf("6 - Reverse print the array\n");
        printf("7 - Quit\n");
        scanf("%d", &userSelection);

        switch (userSelection)
        {
        case 1 :
            size=0;

            while ((size > 20) || (size < 1))
            {
                printf("What is the size of your array? (1 - 20)\n");
                scanf("%d", &size);
                if ((size > 20) || (size < 1))
                {
                    printf("Invalid selection.\n");
                    continue; // to skip the next statements and continue the loop
                }
                arr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*size); // Allocating given size to the dynamic array
                printf("\nSize of array: array[%d]\nReturning...", size);
            }
            break; // Use break between two cases of a switch if two are not meant
                   // execute in a sequence.
        case 2 :
            if (size == 0)
            {
                printf("You should first set the size of the array.\n");
            }
            else
            {
                arrayElements(arr, size); // Always send the size as when you pass array
                                          // it goes to the function as a reference to the array
                                          // Hence, you can't calculate the size in the called function.

                elements = true; // We have populated the array now so have to change the flag.
            }
            break;
        case 3 :
            if (elements == false)
            {
                printf("You should first intitialize the array.\n");
            }
            else
            {
                arraySort(arr, size); // Always send the size as when you pass array
                                      // it goes to the function as a reference to the array
                                      // Hence, you can't calculate the size in the called function.
            }
            break;
        case 4 :
            if (elements == false)
            {
                printf("You should first intitialize the array.\n");
            }
            else
            {
                arrayFind(arr, size);// Always send the size as when you pass array
                                      // it goes to the function as a reference to the array
                                      // Hence, you can't calculate the size in the called function.
            }
            break;
        case 5 :
            if (elements == false)
            {
                printf("You should first intitialize the array.\n");
            }
            else
            {
                arrayPrint(arr, size);// Always send the size as when you pass array
                                      // it goes to the function as a reference to the array
                                      // Hence, you can't calculate the size in the called function.
            }
            break;
        case 6 :
            if (elements == false)
            {
                printf("You should first intitialize the array.\n");
            }
            else
            {
                arrayRevPrint(arr, size);// Always send the size as when you pass array
                                      // it goes to the function as a reference to the array
                                      // Hence, you can't calculate the size in the called function.
            }
            break;
        case 7 :
            printf("Exiting...");
                return 0;
        default :
            printf("That's not a valid choice\n");
        }
    }
}
```

> Note: You have not define the functions ascending() and descending() and that is why I have commented those out. Please write the necessary code for those functions.